# Would have and could have

Tags: grammar

Today when i said "she could have gotten an accident ,if she had not gone  potty." 
Then an english speaker corrected me and said "you mean she would have gotten an accident?" 
In these sentences, i quite didnt understand why i couldn't use could, there was a possiblity that she could have gotten an accident.
Can somebody please explain it to me

Comment: You would say, "She could have **had** an accident if she had not gone potty." I suspect the English speaker didn't understand you correctly, and instead said, "You mean she would have **got in** an accident?" (e.g., like an automobile accident, rather than having a toileting accident). One does not usually "get" an accident; instead one "has" an accident. However, one could "get in" an accident.